# Export JasperReport to PDF OutputStream?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm writing a pretty simple sample project for familiarizing myself with Jasper Reports. I'd like to export a report I've configured to a PDF `OutputStream`, but there's no factory method for it:

```
InputStream template = JasperReportsApplication.class
    .getResourceAsStream("/sampleReport.xml");
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template);
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, String>());
// nope, just chuck testa.  
//JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(report, new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/out.pdf")));
```

How can I get the PDF in an `OutputStream`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ok, so here's how it works; `JasperFillManager` actually returns a `JasperPrint` object, so:

```
// get the JRXML template as a stream
InputStream template = JasperReportsApplication.class
    .getResourceAsStream("/sampleReport.xml");
// compile the report from the stream
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template);
// fill out the report into a print object, ready for export. 
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, String>());
// export it!
File pdf = File.createTempFile("output.", ".pdf");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
```

Enjoy.

Comment: If you're simply trying to output report into a file, you can use `exportReportToPdfFile` without handling outputstream by yourself

Comment: Right, but this way gives me the most flexibility; I can write the output stream to a file or across the network or anywhere I want :)

Comment: Note that compiling is *usually* a superfluous step. Instead, software should fill out the report using the `.jasper` file, rather than re-compiling the `.jrxml` file every time.

Answer (score 18):

> *[JRExporterParameter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporterParameter.html) is deprecated in latest versions, This is a **non deprecated** solution of [@stevemac answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8570284/5292302)*

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Petter");  //why not set some config as we like
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use a JRExporter to export the filled report to different streams and formats.

```
JRExporter exporter = null;

exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Also note that there are other exporters:

```
exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
```

You can find more exporters available here:
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporter.html

They should all accept an OUTPUT_STREAM parameter to control the destination of the report.

Comment: Better because polymorphic

Comment: After 5 years, the JRExportParameter has been deprecated, I have added a non deprecated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35916470/5292302)