# Generate Jasper report with subreport from java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I know how to generate jasper report without any subreport. But currently I have a subreport in my report and I would like to know how can I compile that subreport in java?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can compile the subreport like the simple report - with help of [JasperCompileManager.compileReport(java.lang.String sourceFileName)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html#compileReport%28java.lang.String%29) method, for example.

After that you can pass the compiled subreport as parameter to the master report.

The sample:

```java
JasperReport jasperMasterReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(masterReportSource);
JasperReport jasperSubReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subReportSource);

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap()<String, Object>;
parameters.put("subreportParameter", jasperSubReport);

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperMasterReport, parameters, outputFileName, connection);
```

The snippet from the master report's jrxml file (sample):

```xml
<parameter name="subreportParameter" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
...
<detail>
    <band height="50">
        ...
        <subreport>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="325" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
                <subreportParameter name="City">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="PriceSum" toVariable="ProductTotalPrice" calculation="Sum"/>
                <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[$P{subreportParameter}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
```

---

#### Notes

I mentioned an old API for generating result:
*[JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperReport, String, Map,
                                    java.sql.Connection)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReportToFile-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-java.sql.Connection-)*

In case using *JasperReports 6.x* it is better to use exporters (concrete implementation of *[net.sf.jasperreports.export.Exporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/Exporter.html)* interface, for example *JRPdfExporter*) for generating output file

The example how to use Exporter right can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916470/876298)

Comment: <reportElement x="5" y="25" width="325" height="20"/> Can I make value of x,y,width,height dynamic?

Comment: @VivekYadav Yes, with help of Java API

Comment: I was trying but did not get success. Can you please post an example that how can I do it?

Comment: @VivekYadav You can find samples [here](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/how-to-2/) or [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/noxmldesign/index.html)

Comment: @AlexK thanx for your reply. Its really looking great stuff. I am trying this code on grails but get some problem to implement it properly. Is there any suggestion how to integrate this code with grails. Because its written in purly in java and some code of create problem for implement it properly.

Comment: @VivekYadav If you have the question to ask - you can post it.

Comment: `How can we add multiple sub report in master Dynamically ? ?`

Comment: I added the dataSourceExpression tag (and remove connectionExpression) in my xml and now its working

Comment: Whatis connection?

Comment: @ShadowGames I added info at answer