# JasperReports MasterReport->Subreport->Subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Could anyone give a simple example to call a jasper report with subreport inside subreport from a java program. Something like this ([Generate Jasper report with subreport from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785451/generate-jasper-report-with-subreport-from-java)):

```
JasperReport jasperMasterReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(masterReportSource);
JasperReport jasperSubReport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subReportSource1);
JasperReport jasperSubReport2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subReportSource2);

Map<String, Object> parameters2 = new HashMap()<String, Object>;
parameters2.put("subreportParameter2", jasperSubReport2);

Map<String, Object> parameters1 = new HashMap()<String, Object>;
parameters1.put("subreportParameter1", JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperSubReport1, parameters2, connection));

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperMasterReport, parameters1, connection);
```

MasterReport.jrxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-02T10:06:38 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MasterReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5adfa1b1-651c-478e-a83b-6230d66dc454">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="OracleJDBC"/>
    <parameter name="subreportParameter1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
 <queryString language="SQL">
  <![CDATA[SELECT "PERSON"."ID",
 "PERSON"."FIRST_NAME",
 "PERSON"."LAST_NAME"
FROM "PERSON"]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="FIRST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="LAST_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <columnHeader>
  <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="93" height="16" uuid="cde3f82c-d51e-43ef-a56e-fee3cb853b65"/>
    <textElement>
     <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[PERSONS:]]></text>
   </staticText>
  </band>
 </columnHeader>
 <detail>
  <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="30" height="20" uuid="9fbab9bb-55ec-44c0-badb-501a00334fe6"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="30" height="20" uuid="3c5afed0-442f-41de-9929-abdb8a218981"/>
    <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="30" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="2561523d-322d-487d-89a2-be44804979ee"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIRST_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="431ac382-603e-47a1-b4df-b9d744041718"/>
    <text><![CDATA[FIRST NAME]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="130" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="9b482687-49c6-49f7-b322-ba868e4ce748"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LAST_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4532e6f3-58c0-4c24-aebc-a135309d94ba"/>
    <text><![CDATA[LAST NAME]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <subreport>
    <reportElement x="2" y="40" width="550" height="40" uuid="18ecc4c5-81a1-4ae3-b3f7-3bf10c627be8"/>
    <subreportParameter name="PERSON_ID">
     <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportParameter1}]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport1.jrxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-02T10:11:02 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a0096e3a-50c2-49db-ba13-71afb020c425">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="OracleJDBC"/>
 <parameter name="PERSON_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <parameter name="subreportParameter2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
 <queryString language="SQL">
  <![CDATA[SELECT "PHONE"."ID",
 "PHONE"."PARENT_ID",
 "PHONE"."PHONE_NUMBER"
FROM "PHONE"
WHERE "PHONE"."PARENT_ID" = $P{PERSON_ID} ]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="PARENT_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="PHONE_NUMBER" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <columnHeader>
  <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="26c75f7b-f80c-41ca-a3fc-eb3317026efd"/>
    <textElement>
     <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[PHONES:]]></text>
   </staticText>
  </band>
 </columnHeader>
 <detail>
  <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="454" height="20" uuid="76669766-73b0-47f1-bfff-9337428a4776"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PHONE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="f925e71b-16fe-42ae-8895-143fb886eb63"/>
    <text><![CDATA[PHONE NUMBER:]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="544" height="40" uuid="029f8258-5205-4e91-ae08-e8d8ec55f5e9"/>
    <subreportParameter name="PHONE_ID">
     <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreportParameter2}]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Subreport2.jrxml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-05-02T10:13:15 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9bd68d39-b94b-4e26-94ea-e0dc1e55f226">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="OracleJDBC"/>
 <parameter name="PHONE_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <queryString language="SQL">
  <![CDATA[SELECT "CONTACT_LOG"."ID",
 "CONTACT_LOG"."R_PHONE_ID",
 "CONTACT_LOG"."DSC"
FROM "CONTACT_LOG"
WHERE "CONTACT_LOG"."R_PHONE_ID" = $P{PHONE_ID}]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="R_PHONE_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
 <field name="DSC" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <columnHeader>
  <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15" uuid="0779105f-7c86-4541-906f-ea473cdc3ff5"/>
    <textElement>
     <font isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <text><![CDATA[CONTACTS:]]></text>
   </staticText>
  </band>
 </columnHeader>
 <detail>
  <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="102" y="0" width="448" height="30" uuid="67919643-f890-4121-ac18-59f87b0752f3"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DSC}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7c3824f0-41ff-4e53-8278-dcd0e535efd4"/>
    <text><![CDATA[COMMENT:]]></text>
   </staticText>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the subreport path as main report parameter and get number of subreports like this.

```
            String file = /pathToMainReport/name.jrxml;
            String subreport1 = /pathToSubReport/name1.jasper;
            String subreport2 = /pathToSubReport/name2.jasper;      

            JasperReport jreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file);


            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR1", subreport1);
            map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR2", subreport2);

            JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, map, connection);
```

Comment: Thanks, pariad neupane for your answer, but I think you show me example, two subreports inside the master report: ((MasterReport <-> Subreport1) and (MasterReport <-> Subreport2)), but my problem is difficult: (MasterReport <-> Subreport1 <-> Subreport2).

Comment: well , see this blog. http://hamroblog-sristi.blogspot.com/2011/04/ireport-call-to-subreport-inside.html

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it.

Comment: Yes, hamroblog-sristi.blogspot.com/2011/04/… it work, but I'm exactly want example java code for calling report with parameters <parameter name="Subreport1" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/> (for MasterReport), and <parameter name="Subreport2" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/> (for Subreport1).