# How to store Jasper Report output directly in a database table without any steps in between

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, oracle-apex

It seems to be a simple question, but is it possible to store the output of a JasperReport directly in a database table, without any other steps in between?
As far as I know, Jasper produces an output (e.g. PDF) which I can download and/or show in the browser. To store it into the database I need an extra step to transfer the PDF from the file system to a database table.
The reason for that request is, that I must generate and persist a receipt for a transaction.

My programming environment is:

- Oracle APEX
- Oracle Database 11.0.2
- Apache Tomcat

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Dave, for your answer. Of course I can store the result PDF in the database with APEX, that is not the question. I want to store it directly from Jasper without any other steps between.

Comment: [JasperReports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/) is a Java library. [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) is an IDE for developing report templates that are filled out using said library. Neither the IDE nor JasperReports have built-in functionality for streaming filled reports to a database. Custom software is required. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8349906/59087) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569883/59087).

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite good solution. To generate a PDF out of Oracle APEX with JasperReports there is a integration framework called  [JasperReportsIntegration](http://www.opal-consulting.de/apex/f?p=20090928:4:0)
This framework contains several functions to connect Oracle APEX with Jasper. There is also a function to get the report as a blob. This blob can saved easily in a database table.

```
begin
  xlib_jasperreports.set_report_url('<url of the Application>');

  xlib_jasperreports.get_report(p_rep_name          => :p_rep_name,
                                p_rep_format        => :p_rep_format,
                                p_data_source       => :p_data_source,
                                p_rep_locale        => :p_rep_locale,
                                p_rep_encoding      => :p_rep_encoding,
                                p_additional_params => :p_additional_params,
                                p_out_blob          => :p_out_blob,
                                p_out_mime_type     => :p_out_mime_type);
end;
```

This works perfect for me.