# JasperReports unable to export PDF files

Tags: java, spring, maven, jasper-reports

I'm trying to write simple code to export JasperPrint to pdf file. To be precise, write bytes into HTTP response.

My simple code looks like this:

```
public static void writePdfReport(final JasperPrint jp,
                                  final HttpServletResponse response,
                                  final String reportName) throws IOException, JRException {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
            "inline; filename=" + (reportName == null ? jp.getName() : reportName).replace('"', '_') + ".pdf");

    final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

    final byte[] pdfBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jp);
    response.setContentLength(pdfBytes.length);

    final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfBytes);
    IOUtils.copy(bais, outStream);

    outStream.flush();
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outStream);
}
```

My Maven pom file:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

The problem is that whenever I call `writePdfReport` function, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontMapper

    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:214)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(JasperExportManager.java:544)
    at com.kendaxa.fexcom.core.reports.ReportWriter.writePdfReport(ReportWriter.java:31)
    at com.kendaxa.fexcom.core.reports.GenericTableReportSpec.Should generate simple table PDF report(GenericTableReportSpec.groovy:100)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.pdf.FontMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more
```

I did my research, first, it seems that the problem is in the JasperReports library suggested here (4 years old): [Dependency error in jasper-reports from itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314373/dependency-error-in-jasper-reports-from-itext)

However, applying an accepted answer does not help, even with the newest version I get the same error.

I've also tried a different approach for exporting files inspired from here [Export JasperReport to PDF OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568945/export-jasperreport-to-pdf-outputstream) without any luck.

Does anyone have an up-to-date working solution for exporting pdf files?
Thank you for any hep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The com.lowagie.text.pdf.FontMapper class does exist in the 2.1.7 version of com.lowagie.itext jar.

Are you using this exact version as a dependency?  In my working example this is the version I use.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
   <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are already doing that, I would make sure your runtime environment has only this 2.1.7 version of the itext jar.  Is it possible another version of itext is getting included in the deployed jar library?

I pushed a working example to https://github.com/cameronhurd/simple-jasper-report